# MouseLeave event on a BezierSegment does not get called in the convex hull of the curve

Tags: c#, wpf, events, bezier

I have attached the events directly to the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) object. The MouseMove event gets called even when the mouse position in the convex hull of the BezierSegment. When the mouse moves out of the hull, the MouseLeave event gets called. What possibly could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. The `MouseLeave` event is *supposed* to fire when the mouse cursor leaves the bounds of the relevant object. The convex hull *is* the bounds of the `Path` object.

From the [UIElement.MouseLeave Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx) page at MSDN:

> Occurs when the mouse pointer leaves the bounds of this element.
>
> Although MouseLeave tracks when the mouse leaves an element, this event more literally reports that the IsMouseOver property value has changed from true to false on this element.

There is also nothing wrong with the `MouseMove` event... it is *supposed* to work across the whole screen, otherwise, how could you drag an object across the screen?

Comment: To confirm if the convex hull is in the bounds of the path, I created a sample wpf application, with just a path(having a BezierSegment). But MouseLeave was called when I crossed the path into the convex hull region.